# Setup virtualhost where localhost working on 81 port in apache zendserver

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, zend-framework2, virtualhost

I have installed zendserver and it is running on **`http://localhost:81/`**.

Now I have created **zend framework 2** project in **Apache2/htdocs/zend2** and accessing this through `http://localhost:81/zend2/public`.

I have to set virtual host for this like **zend.local** but it is not working.

In httpd.conf file

```
NameVirtualHost *:81
<VirtualHost *:81>
<Directory "C:\Program Files/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/zend2/public">
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
DocumentRoot C:\Program Files/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/zend2/public/
ServerName  zend.local
ServerAlias zend.local
</VirtualHost>
```

and In hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 zend.local
```

I have tried all possibilities but nothing works.

Comment: Did you restart the apache?

Comment: already tried but no success.

Comment: you must set 127.0.0.1:81

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing ubuntu for development i dont see how your doing it on windows and how it doesn’t annoy you.

try this:

make a copy of the default portion and just add ServerName Zend.local then modify the paths and that should work. You might also want to try restarting the computer that sometimes makes it work (rare occasions)

here is a copy of mine that works but its under ubuntu so it might or might not work for you.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#ZEND-{354B5BC7F803049AB79DE95C47F32B59}
Include "/usr/local/zend/etc/sites.d/zend-default-vhost-80.conf"
#ZEND-{354B5BC7F803049AB79DE95C47F32B59}
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName zendapp.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/zendapp/public
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/zendapp/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
#ZEND-{90331A19916187EEA0C9B3A8FE0E1632}
Include "/usr/local/zend/etc/sites.d/globals-*.conf"
Include "/usr/local/zend/etc/sites.d/vhost_*.conf"
#ZEND-{90331A19916187EEA0C9B3A8FE0E1632}
```